# Download error aiocsv. How to install the module?

Tags: python, csv, download

Please help me with the download error.

I am trying to install the aiocsv library for my project, however when downloading with
pip install aiocsv getting error.
How can I fix it and install this module?

error code:

pip install aiocsv
Collecting aiocsv
Using cached aiocsv-1.2.3.tar.gz (62 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: aiocsv
Building wheel for aiocsv (setup.py) ... error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\professional\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Professional\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u9fs0atd\\aiocsv_f33954bb06d443e99eaccd0d3ef87399\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Professional\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u9fs0atd\\aiocsv_f33954bb06d443e99eaccd0d3ef87399\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-2xniq_zi'
       cwd: C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u9fs0atd\aiocsv_f33954bb06d443e99eaccd0d3ef87399\
  Complete output (18 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  file aiocsv.py (for module aiocsv) not found
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.9
  creating build\lib.win32-3.9\aiocsv
  copying aiocsv\parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\aiocsv
  copying aiocsv\protocols.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\aiocsv
  copying aiocsv\readers.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\aiocsv
  copying aiocsv\writers.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\aiocsv
  copying aiocsv\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\aiocsv
  copying aiocsv\py.typed -> build\lib.win32-3.9\aiocsv
  copying aiocsv\_parser.pyi -> build\lib.win32-3.9\aiocsv
  file aiocsv.py (for module aiocsv) not found
  running build_ext
  building 'aiocsv._parser' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

---

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiocsv
  Running setup.py clean for aiocsv
Failed to build aiocsv
Installing collected packages: aiocsv
    Running setup.py install for aiocsv ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\professional\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Professional\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u9fs0atd\\aiocsv_f33954bb06d443e99eaccd0d3ef87399\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Professional\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-u9fs0atd\\aiocsv_f33954bb06d443e99eaccd0d3ef87399\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-nyjq06ux\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\professional\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\Include\aiocsv'
         cwd: C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u9fs0atd\aiocsv_f33954bb06d443e99eaccd0d3ef87399\
    Complete output (18 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    file aiocsv.py (for module aiocsv) not found
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.9
    creating build\lib.win32-3.9\aiocsv
    copying aiocsv\parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\aiocsv
    copying aiocsv\protocols.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\aiocsv
    copying aiocsv\readers.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\aiocsv
    copying aiocsv\writers.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\aiocsv
    copying aiocsv\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.9\aiocsv
    copying aiocsv\py.typed -> build\lib.win32-3.9\aiocsv
    copying aiocsv\_parser.pyi -> build\lib.win32-3.9\aiocsv
    file aiocsv.py (for module aiocsv) not found
    running build_ext
    building 'aiocsv._parser' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1